# squeak error: cannot write a read-only file

Tags: squeak

I am trying to write a new method in Squeak. I click on the "no messages" to create a new method but any change to the existing template produces the error

"Error: cannot write a read-only file"

Comment: Where did you install Squeak? There should be an .image file accompanied by a .changes file. Both must be writable while you develop in Squeak. In particular, each method that you save will be written to the changes file.

Comment: Thanks you solved my problem. I found the changes file and messed with it until it worked

Answer (score 1):

Squeak comes with an .image file and a .changes file. You must ensure that both are writable at development time. In particular, each time you save a method it will be written to the changes file.